# Importing Mediapipe in Python leads to 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'message_types_by_name' error. How to solve it?

Tags: python, computer-vision, protocol-buffers, mediapipe

**MediaPipe importing issue**

i tried to import cv2 and mediapipe to use handmarks but it keeps showing this error.
i also matched the version of protobuf with it and copied the builder.py from the last version of protobuf to the matched version but it resists

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\python\pythonn\CV\proj.py", line 2, in <module>
    import mediapipe as mp
  File "C:\Users\arad2504\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    import mediapipe.python.solutions as solutions 
  File "C:\Users\arad2504\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solutions\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    import mediapipe.python.solutions.drawing_styles
  File "C:\Users\arad2504\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solutions\drawing_styles.py", line 20, in <module>
    from mediapipe.python.solutions.drawing_utils import DrawingSpec
  File "C:\Users\arad2504\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solutions\drawing_utils.py", line 24, in <module>
    from mediapipe.framework.formats import detection_pb2
  File "C:\Users\arad2504\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\framework\formats\detection_pb2.py", line 14, in <module>
    from mediapipe.framework.formats import location_data_pb2 as mediapipe_dot_framework_dot_formats_dot_location__data__pb2
  File "C:\Users\arad2504\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\framework\formats\location_data_pb2.py", line 14, in <module>
    from mediapipe.framework.formats.annotation import rasterization_pb2 as mediapipe_dot_framework_dot_formats_dot_annotation_dot_rasterization__pb2
  File "C:\Users\arad2504\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\framework\formats\annotation\rasterization_pb2.py", line 19, in <module>
    _builder.BuildMessageAndEnumDescriptors(DESCRIPTOR, _globals)
  File "C:\Users\arad2504\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\builder.py", line 64, in BuildMessageAndEnumDescriptors
    for (name, msg_des) in file_des.message_types_by_name.items():
**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'message_types_by_name'**
```